# Where can I post my article and get some feedback?

Tags: advice, online-resources, article-writing

So I was bored (because Quarantine) so I decided to write an article about a random math topic. Where can I "post" my paper for other to see and submit some feedback? Because I thought that I could use some feedback to improve my proofs and things like that that go into writing an article so that I can improve my math skills overall... Is there any online platform for that purpose? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps start a blog.

Comment: Maybe https://vixra.org

Comment: It would be awesome if https://writing.stackexchange.com maintained an academic writing community within it, but I guess it doesn’t.

Comment: Maybe reddit?${}$